# What is the correct reading of $A+B+C$?

Tags: arithmetic, binary-operations, associativity

We have many operations where when we write it in a form that does not make it explicit which expressions are the inputs to which operands, for example $1-1-1$ is a form. **Is there a name for this kind of form?**
Given this expression, we can use the fact that $-$ is left associative so $1-1-1$ has a specific form of a $-$ operation that takes $1-1$ as the left input and $-1$ as the right input giving us $(1-1)-1$.

If we take $A+B+C$, we don't know as clearly if it is $(A+B)+C$ or $A+(B+C)$. Does $A+B+C$ have a standard form that such as subtraction where we can deduce a clear structure where we know which values are the inputs of which operations? **Is there a standard way where $+$ is treated as either left or right associative, or do we just accept that due to the general associativity of $+$ that $A+B+C$ will always have a specific value and it will be the same no matter the choice of left or right associativity?**

Because it seems strange to have an expression where we know it's value but not precisely the order of operations, **does the expression have a specific well-ordered representation or is it a shorthand for any sum?****

In this way is $A+B+C$ the same as saying: 'Any possible sum of $A$, $B$ or $C$.'

I've been told that addition is both left and right associative, which would imply there's two ways of viewing A+B+C.

Comment: For a non associative operation, writing $A+B+C$ would be ill defined.  For instance, $A\div B\div C$ is ill defined.  such notation should be avoided.

Comment: @lulu Uhm... (some) People like avoiding $a\div b\div c$ and $a/b/c$, but nobody on Earth avoids $a-b-c$.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio  For $a-b-c$ I agree that it is at least widely accepted that one should read it as $(a-b)-c$.  I don't think that extends to every binary operation, however.  Though, it is true that both Wolfram Alpha and Excel parse $A/B/C$ analogously.  That is, they read it as $(A/B)/C$.  So maybe it's more universal than I thought?  Still seems to me like a good thing to avoid.

Comment: All such forms are interpreted in terms of convention, rather than a mathematical rule. You can’t deduce the meaning - it is language rather than math. The “language” is an “order of operations.” The language is designed for clarity - if we include all the required parentheses in our expressions, they become a bit noisy.

Comment: We know that $(a+b)+c$ and $a+(b+c)$ denote the same value, so we define the expression $a+b+c$ to denote that value.

Comment: The rule that is usually taught in school is that, unless otherwise stated, the leftmost binary operation is evaluated first. This is taugth in Italy and, I must assume, in the rest of the western world. It should be noted that there isn't universal agreement over the order of exponentiation *when expressed with the caret ${}^\land$ symbol*. Some authors say $a^{\land}b^\land c=a^{\land}(b^\land c)$, but for instance Excel and Matlab say $a^{\land}b^\land c=(a^{\land}b)^\land c$.

Comment: It is usual, for operations of the same type, to go left right. This applies to $A+B+C,$ $A-B-C$, $A+B-C,$ and $A-B+C,$ because $+$ and $-$ are the same “type.” Left-right doesn’t apply, by convention, to operations of mixed type. For example, $a+b\cdot c$ is interpreted as $a+(b\cdot c)$ because $\cdot$  has “higher precedence” than $+.$ But the key is, the meaning is entirely convention.

Comment: If you are working in an environment with a lot of weird binary operators, like $\star,$ or when $+$ or $\cdot$ are not associative, you might want to specify explicitly how to read such expressions, just to communicate clearly. The order of operations is, in the end, a tool for communicating clearly, not a mathematical rule.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews it's usual but I've seen + be described as both left and right associative

Comment: @lulu is $a-b-c$ not defined? I have seen it before, this is incorrect, I assume the understanding of $a-b-c$ is $(a-b)-c$?

Comment: @Karl so we can say that $a+b+c$ as an expression is not the best but it's essentially like saying 'there is a value we can get from the addition of these numbers in any combination and it will be the same anyway'

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio Usually the form $a \uparrow b \uparrow c$ should be interpreted as $a \uparrow (b \uparrow c)$ purely because $(a \uparrow b) \uparrow c$ is boringly the same as $a \uparrow (b c)$. U use uparrow rather than caret because I can't work out how to include a caret in $\LaTeX$ without it being interpreted into the conventional exponential notation.

Comment: @user37577  For subtraction, I agree that $a-b-c$ is to be read as $(a-b)-c$.  More broadly, I suppose, one could "deduce" this if we interpret $a-b$ as $a+(-b)$.  Similarly, if we interpret $a\div b$ as $a\times \left(\frac 1b\right)$ we can "deduce" the analog in that case.  But, again, I would not extend this reading to general binary operations.  $a^{b^c}$ is generally read as $a^{(b^c)}$ and not $\left(a^b\right)^c$.  To stress:  these are conventions, whether universal or not.  They are not examples of broad mathematical principles.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio : There is general agreement by writers using the “standard” keyboard that $a_1$^$\cdots$^$a_n$ means $a_1$^$(a_2$^$\cdots$^$a_n)$. This is to avoid having to write lots of parentheses. Using the opposite convention, namely left association, would save only one pair of parentheses, since $a_1$^$\cdots$^$a_n$ could then be written as $a_1$^$(a_2\cdots a_n)$.

Answer (score 1):

> If we take $A+B+C$, we don't know as clearly if it is $(A+B)+C$ or $A+(B+C)$.

Then $+$ is not properly defined.  In most cases, `+` is the operation in some (abelian) group, thus the operation is associative by definition, hence the placing of `()` does not play a role.

And even if it would make a difference, `()` can be dropped, if the operation is to be defined left- or right-associative.  Most prominent example is IEEE floating-point arithmetic, where neither `+` nor `*` are associative.  The exact definition is in the specification of the arithmetic or programming language — or in the mathematical definition.

> Because it seems strange to have an expression where we know it's value but not precisely the order of the inputs.

It's not about the *order* of the inputs, it's about the priority of operations.  If it's about the *order* of operations, then it's about whether the operation is *abelien* or *commutative* or *symmetric*.

Anyway, it's quite common that representations are *not* unique.  Much more common than unique representations.  It's just the case that if a representation happens to be unique, then it's usually much more emphasized or even crucial in proofs, like

- Uniqueness of prime factorization of natural numbers (up to ordering of the primes).
- Uniqueness of power series expansion of an analytic function at some point.

Representations like *"represent a number as a sum of three numbers"* is usually inherently non-unique, and it can be a field of study in it's own right to find how many of specific representations / decompositions there are. See for example [partition function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_function_(number_theory)).

> for example $1−1−1$ is a form. Is there a name for this kind of form?

It's non-associative (in general.  And also not abelian in general). Usually such expressions are evalated left-to-right.  But there are notable exceptions, like $$a^{b^c} = a^{(b^c)}\neq (a^b)^c  = a^{b\cdot c}$$  This might even be the case in programming, for example the above can be expressed in python as

`a**b**c = a**(b**c)`

which is how Python implements it.